# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable while creating an empty dictionary in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I tried to create an empty dictionary, like below.

```
>>> dict1 = dict()
I am seeing the below error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you defined a `dict` variable elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Mmm, this error is on line 1. Are you using ipython?

Comment: @roganjosh In the interactive console, every line is line 1.

Comment: Eh, then I'm going off-course. In iPython, trampling a builtin is permanent until it's reset.